# Duplicate classes among kotlin-runtime and kotlin-stdlib

Tags: android, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to add a library to an android project's gradle.build file

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.squash:squash-sqlite:0.2.4"
```

but when building the app, I get a lot of errors similar to this:

```
  Duplicate class kotlin.DslMarker found in modules kotlin-runtime-1.2.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:1.2.21) and kotlin-stdlib-1.3.41.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41)
```

the error disappears after removing the mentioned dependency ,,

how to resolve such conflicts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude `kotlin-runtime` artifact entirely from your dependencies. 
In fact it's no longer being published since Kotlin 1.3.